# Is there an automated way to find out which node modules were used with a package.json on a specific date?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

**Situation:**

I have a `package.json` from 08.12.2014 with all module versions using minor-update format "~1.0.0".

There is no trace of the modules that actually have been used to build a `release.js` and a `min.js`, but there is an issue bound to those minor-updates and the project can't be rebuild again.

**Problem:**

Except for a very tedious attempt to sherlock those versions and checking each module history, I was wondering if there was a npm method or some automated way to solve this.

like `npm install -date 08.12.2014` or a github api call?

Is there a way to do this automated?

**Solution ideas:**

Without any deeper knowledge of npm or github I would guess there might be an api or some projects that might be used or combined to crawl through github based on a package.json. There does not seem to be a solution ready for use.

Comment: I the took the sherlock road and determined all versions manually - at least for our direct dependencies. I did not have the time to step through all sub-dependencies too. That would be a task for the automated script, if there isn't any yet, I'll put this to my pile of project ideas :)